# Dynamic Application/Sign Up Form

Tags: php, vb.net, user-interface, registration, user-registration

I'm wanting to create a simple VB.NET application which asks someone for their details. I'm not worried about the back-end of the code, I plan on sending the data to a MS Azure SQL Server and I know how to do this. My question is regarding the actual UI for the user. Much like I've seen PHP do on webpages I want a form that dynamically changes to the users input. For exmaple, when `txtAccountType` `=` `"Brozne"` I'd like a handful of textboxes and lables to disappear, for new ones to appear and for the application to automatically refresh the view, if this makes sense?

To be a little clearer here's an example:

> Name: Garry
>
> MembershipType: Gold
>
> OrderID: 001
>
> RefID: 0009

---

But when `MembershipType = "Bronze"` i'd like the `OrderID` to disappear and for `RefID` to take its place on the screen.

> Name: Garry
>
> MembershipType: Gold
>
> RefID: 0009

I know I could manually code this to make things invisible in the UI, but that seams like a massive amount of code for something so simple. And it doesnt really make it easy to add new things into the questions in the future.

Is anyone familiar with any components or anything that might at least help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using PHP+HTML?

```
$txtAccountType = $_POSTS['txtAccountType']; //OR OTHER METHOD TO GET VALUE

if($txtAccountType = "Brozne") {
    echo "<input type='text' name='input1' />";
    echo "<input type='text' name='input2' />";
    ..
    etc
} else { //AccountType NOT Bronze
    echo "<input type='text' name='otherinput1' />";
    echo "<input type='text' name='otherinput1' />";
    ..
    etc
}
```

For the invisible ID's you can use this in the fields:

```
style="display:none;"
```

Example:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='refid' style="display:none;" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the txtAccounttype.TextChanged Event in your code.

Private Sub txtAccounttype_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAccounttype.TextChanged

// and Everything you need to do, goes in here

```
End Sub
```